# Let $f(x)=\exp(-a|x|)$ and $a>0$. Show that there exists $C$ and $\alpha$ such that $|f(x)-f(y)|\le\frac{C|x-y|}{1+x^2}$ for $|x-y|\le\alpha$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, inequality, contest-math

Let $f(x)=\exp(-a|x|)$ and $a>0$. Show that there exists $C$ and $\alpha$ such that $$|f(x)-f(y)|\le\frac{C|x-y|}{1+x^2}$$ for $|x-y|\le\alpha$.

---

From the mean value theorem, given any $x,y$ with $|x-y|\le\alpha$, we have $|f(x)-f(y)|=|x-y||f'(\xi)|$ for some $\xi$ between $x,y$. So for $x,y$ positive, $f'(x)=-a\exp(-ax)$ and $|f'(\xi)|=a\exp(-a\xi)\le a\cdot\max\{\exp(-ax),\exp(-ay)\}$, which we want to show is less than or equal to $\frac{C}{1+x^2}$.

Comment: you pretty much solve this problem already. You still stuck on proving the last equality that $a \max\{\exp(-ax),\exp(-ay)\}\le C/(1+x^2)?$

Comment: Yeah we want to show $a(1+x^2)\max\{\exp(-ax),\exp(-ay\}$ is bounded above by a constant $C$.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if this works: The simple case is for x, y > 0. Assume y > x . So from the mean value theorem apply to f(t) =$e^{-at}$ on [x, y], you already have: |f(x) - f(y)| = a*$e^{-ar}|x - y|$ <$ a/(1 + ar + 0.5(ar)^2)*|x - y|$< $a/(1 + ax + 0.5(ax)^2)*|x - y|$.

Now you want a C > 0 such that:
$a/(1 + ax + 0.5(ax)^2) < C/(1 + x^2)$ <=> $a/(1 + 0.5(ax)^2)$ < $C/(1 + x^2)$ <=>$ a + ax^2 < C + 0.5Ca^2x^2.$ So choose C = max{a, 2/a} > 0